# World's largest scrotum?

Tags: medical-science, biology

I found a video on YouTube proclaiming to be showing [the world's largest scrotum](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZneGwS6t594). [Caution: Video contains disturbing images and may be not safe for work settings.]

After searching online, I can't find news articles nor otherwise explaining how this would happen or verifying if this is real.

Is the video real?  And if so, what could have caused this condition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks to me like the classic elephantiasis sufferer.

[Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Elephantiasis) has more detail on the disease itself. It sounds unverified what the final cause of the thickening skin is:

> However, the disease itself is a result of a complex interplay between several factors: the worm, the symbiotic Wolbachia bacteria within the worm, the host’s immune response, and the numerous opportunistic infections and disorders that arise.

Comment: That's a terrible disease.  +1 for good information included with an answer that makes sense.

Comment: I have removed an photograph image. It was possibly not safe-for-work; I didn't want to censor it, but merely place it behind a link. However, the source for the image was not cited, and there was no credit to the original copyright owner, so I was unable to do so. I will [raise a meta-question](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/on-not-safe-for-work-images) on the topic because I don't want to be seen as censoring medical images.

Comment: Good call @Oddthinking. My apologies.

Comment: No problems, Rory. If you have a link for the original image, we could put that back in there (with a NSFW warning) so interested people can confirm that your diagnosis is plausible.

Comment: +1 Another possibility is [Hydrocele Testis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrocele_testis) though I'm unsure if they can grow that large.